# Why can't I catch this iOS AWS SDK network error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, try-catch

I'm using the [AWS iOS SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/index.html) in my app, and I recently tested a no-network situation. This is my code:

```
dispatch_queue_t Q = dispatch_queue_create("ec2_instance_fetch", NULL);
dispatch_async(Q, ^{
    AmazonEC2Client *client = [[AmazonEC2Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:[ESCredentialsManager accessKey] withSecretKey:[ESCredentialsManager secretKey]];
    client.endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@", [ESRegionManager endpointForRegion:[ESRegionManager activeRegionObject]]];
    EC2DescribeInstancesResponse *response = [client describeInstances:[[EC2DescribeInstancesRequest alloc] init]];
    NSMutableArray *temp = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (EC2Reservation *reserv in response.reservations) {
        for (EC2Instance *instance in reserv.instances) {
            [temp addObject:instance];
        }
    }
    self.instances = temp;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

In a no connection situation, it throws this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AmazonClientException', reason: 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x16e55460 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSUnderlyingError=0x16dea2c0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x301adf4b 0x3a91c6af 0xbbae1 0xbb31d 0xba6c7 0xba177 0xbd3ab 0xa2bab 0x3adffd1b 0x3ae06273 0x3ae0606b 0x3ae06ce1 0x3ae06f59 0x3af41dbf 0x3af41c84)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type AmazonServiceException
(lldb)
```

So I tried to simply catch the error like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t Q = dispatch_queue_create("ec2_instance_fetch", NULL);
dispatch_async(Q, ^{
    @try {
        AmazonEC2Client *client = [[AmazonEC2Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:[ESCredentialsManager accessKey] withSecretKey:[ESCredentialsManager secretKey]];
        client.endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@", [ESRegionManager endpointForRegion:[ESRegionManager activeRegionObject]]];
        EC2DescribeInstancesResponse *response = [client describeInstances:[[EC2DescribeInstancesRequest alloc] init]];
        NSMutableArray *temp = @[].mutableCopy;
        for (EC2Reservation *reserv in response.reservations) {
            for (EC2Instance *instance in reserv.instances) {
                [temp addObject:instance];
            }
        }
        self.instances = temp;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
    @catch (NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
});
```

But it still fails with the same error, and the app crashes. Why can't I catch this error this way? How can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't catch `NSError`. Catch `NSException`.

Comment: So instead of `@catch (NSError *error)` I should do `@catch (NSException *exception)` ? Why does it make a difference?

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure *why*, though - what's different between the two?

Comment: This isn't Java. `NSError` has nothing to do with exceptions. It's just a class for holding details about errors. Actual exceptions are based on the `NSException` class.

Comment: am doing same but its not working  -@catch (AmazonServiceException *serviceException) {
        // Handle serviceException.
    }
    @catch (AmazonClientException *clientException) {
        // Handle clientException.
    } but still its crashing ma app with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AmazonClientException', reason: 'The specified file cannot be re any idea?